# Spring Controller in Gradle Netbeans project doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc, netbeans, gradle, thymeleaf, spring-4

I'm trying to build a Spring project based on `Gradle` Using `Netbeans` IDE

I created a gradle project and modified `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'jason.main'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'
}

//Gretty Embedded Jetty
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

// Don't use Jetty8, even it's a servlet 3.0+ container, 
// but not support non-jar WebApplicationInitializer scanning.
// It will cause "No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath"
gretty {
  port = 8080
  contextPath = 'jason'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9' //tomcat7 or tomcat8
}


sourceSets{
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'jason'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'resources'
            include '**'
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Project Tree :

[image]

and this is `test.java` :

```
package jason;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class test {

    @RequestMapping("/AA")
    public String hi(Model model){
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

so when i try to run the project , it runs but when i try to go to the following url :

`http://localhost:8080/jason/AA` it gives me this error :

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /jason/AA. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found Powered by Jetty://
> ```

What i have missed ? with noticing that i want to you `Thymeleaf` as a template engine

Comment: What is the name of the war?

Comment: @Jens the  name is `jason.war` and when i login this url `http://localhost:8080/jason` it gives me this message true `Directory: /jason/
`

Comment: You have activated component-scan?

Comment: Hmm don't know , can you explain more or how can i check ?

Comment: Please show your spring configuration.

Comment: Please have a look on the image above  , these are the files there , almost i didn't do Spring config ? or you mean these config inside build.gradle ?